# extra column in a JFace TreeViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, treeviewer

I've a strange problem ...

by creating a (Jface) tree viewer with few column I always got created one more (emtpy) ....

```
/// TreeViewer creation:
        treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

/// TreeViewerColumn creation!
    for (int column = 0; column < columnsToAdd; column++) {
        final TreeViewerColumn treeColumnText = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewer, SWT.LEFT | SWT.BORDER);
        treeColumnText.getColumn().setWidth(columnWidth);
        treeColumnText.getColumn().setMoveable(false);
        treeColumnText.getColumn().setText(model.getColumnName(column));
        treeColumnText.setLabelProvider(columnLProvider[column]);
        treeColumnText.getColumn().pack();
    }
```

any idea why?

************* UPDATE

the parent of the treeViewer is the personsTabFolder:

```
personsTabFolder = new CTabFolder(persons, SWT.NONE);
```

just to highlight, I don't call any .layout(); on personsTabFolder!

_ _

Kasper

Comment: What is the Layout being used by `parent`? The layout may be increasing the size of the tree viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! 
was using a CTabItem instead of a TabItem.